# Can i modify the CSS of a marker icon on an event (make it bigger) with leaflet

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet

I'm actually using leaflet into an Angular service, i generate my markers icons with this method:

```
  private getIcon(geoJsonPoint) {
if (geoJsonPoint.properties.actif_id) {
  const category = geoJsonPoint.properties.category.toUpperCase();
  const prioritie = geoJsonPoint.properties.priority.toUpperCase();
  const id = geoJsonPoint.properties.id;
  console.log(geoJsonPoint);
  const url = 'assets/images/' + category + '/' + prioritie + '.svg';
  return L.icon({
    iconUrl: url,
    className: id,
    iconSize: [58, 68],
    iconAnchor: [29, 68],
    popupAnchor: [0, -60]
  });
```

so on leaflet event (popupen) i want to make my icons bigger without set a new icon but only with css modifications. Is leaflet permits this kind of thing or does someone has already done this ?

Thx for help !

Comment: I managed to resolve this using DomUtil and SetTransform, below the code (i wanted to transform on the event popupopen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it using L.DomUtil and setTransform,i post the code below if it can help anyone. I precise i wanted to transform the icon on popupopen event.

```
  private zoomIconOnPopupOpen(scale): void {
this.map.on('popupopen', (event1: any) => {
  let marker = event1.popup._source;
  if (marker._icon) {
    const pos = L.DomUtil.getPosition(marker._icon);
    L.DomUtil.setTransform(marker._icon, pos, scale);
  }
});
this.map.on('popupclose', (event1: any) => {
  let marker = event1.popup._source;
  if (marker._icon) {
    const pos = L.DomUtil.getPosition(marker._icon);
    L.DomUtil.setTransform(marker._icon, pos, 1);
  }
});
```

}